# Remove PasspointConfiguration on Android API Level 29

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm trying to remove Passpoint Configuration on Android (using Kotlin) API level 29, but I'm getting some issues. It can't remove or list properly the PassPointConfiguration. Then I was reading the documentation and could find that are deprecated method on API level 29, but unfortunately the documentation don't advice any other method to list and remove the Passpoint configuration.

In some research I've found someone advising to use WifiNetworkSuggestion, but on API level 29 the suggestion does not pop up any message and for API 30 and 28 it pops up though.

Is there anyone here have any suggestion on how to list and remove the passpoint configuration on API level 29 ?For API 28 and 30 I don't have this problem.

Piece of code to list the PasspointConfigurations

```
val wifi = context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE) as WifiManager
val config = wifi.passpointConfigurations
```

Piece of code to remove PasspointConfiguration

```
wifi.removePasspointConfiguration(fqdn)
```